# How can I get the second derivative and the reciprocal from the result of NDSolve?

Tags: plotting

I have obtained a result h(x) from NDSolve [data](http://www.wikiupload.com/HQC3QXIP0Y0UX02). I can plot it

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\data.dat"];
ListLinePlot@data
```

[image]

Now I want to get the 2-nd order derivative of h(x) with respect to x, i.e. hxx, and the reverse of h(x), i.e. h^-1, in order to proceeding other calculation, such as, to plot the function of h^-2-hxx. Anyone can give me some guides or advice on this issue? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's pretend this is your data

```
dat = Table[{x, 2 Sin[x]^2 + Cos[2 x]^2}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/100}]
```

Ok, not your data, but similar enough

```
ListPlot@dat
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

we create an [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) function

```
 f = Interpolation[dat]
```

and then just calculate derivatives and inverse

```
Plot[
 {
  f[x]
  , f''[x]
  , 1/f[x]
  }
 , {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi, @rhermans. Thanks for your helpful and rapid reply!